# Compare current record with MongoDB existing record in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

i am traversing cvs file line by line using python. I need to compare 2 columns of the current record with the existing records in MongoDB. If not present insert it into mongo, else if; need to compare all the fields of the current record with the existing record in mongoDB and current record would be inserted in the place of old record and only changes in fields would be saved in History json in same document.

Existing record in MongoDB:

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("59661c4d5e2bb8a9c80e74b8"), 
  "ID" : 149, 
  "UID" : "2017-06-01__ccm-401__238AC3E",
  "Date" : "2017-06-01", 
  "Timestamp" : "2017-06-01 08:00:14",
  "UCM" : "ccm-401",
  "Description" : "SJC08-1-LOBBY", 
  "Site" : "SJC", 
  "Building" : "SJC08", 
  "Floor" : 1, 
  "Room_Name" : "LOBBY", 
  "MAC" : "SEP001DA238AC3E"
}
```

Current record:

```
{
  "ID" : 149, 
  "UID" : "2017-06-05__ccm-401__238AC3E",
  "Date" : "2017-06-01", 
  "Timestamp" : "2017-06-01 08:00:14",
  "UCM" : "ccm-402",
  "Description" : "SJC08-1-LOBBY",
  "Site" : "SSC",
  "Building" : "SJC08",
  "Floor" : 1, 
  "Room_Name" :"LOBBY",
  "MAC" : "SEP001DA238AC3E"
}
```

Here Validation fields are "Description" and "MAC". If these two fields of the current record is same as existing record in MongoDB, then need to compare other fields of the record. In this case difference is in ID,UCM,Site field, so need to maintain dictionary of changes like below...

```
COLL {
'uid':  
'mac':
'name':
'ip':
'status':
'date':
.
.
'config_history':
[
      {
       'date':
       'status':
       'ip':
       .
       .
       },
     {
      'date':
      'status':
      'ip':
      .
      .
     }
 ]
}
```

Note: MongoDB is remote access server, so can't do operation like local machine operations

Comment: I think that I understand what you are trying to do... My best recommandation would be to transform your CSV line into a Dictionary, then use a library such as [`deepdiff`](https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff) to control what are the differences.

Comment: Hi Fabien, Thanks for ur suggestions... i am new to python and mongo, it would be great if you could provide me detailed code structure.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you have a CSV with columns separated by `;` you can compare with mongo documents by this way:

```
csv_lines = open('myfile.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')
# Iterate over lines
for line in csv_lines:
 # Break the line to get the columns
 cols = line.split(';')
 # Build an object for comparison
 csv_dict = {
  'UID' : cols[0],
  'MAC' : cols[1],
  # etc, etc. the key names are equal to the one in Mongo whenever it is possible
 }
 # compare
 cursor = collection.find({
  'UID' : csv_dict['UID'],
  # etc. with other match criterias
 })
 # Check if we have documents
 if cursor.count():
  # Yes, browse the results
  for document in cursor:
   # Perform deeper comparison by looking all the keys in csv_dict
   for key in csv_dict:
    # Is key missing in Mongo?
    if key not in document:
     # Missing key
    elif csv_dict[key] != document[key]
     # Different value
```